# What are the practical differences between "podman save" and "podman push" for creating local OCI archives of locally-built images?

Tags: podman

I'm wondering what the practical difference is between `podman save` and `podman push` when creating a local OCI archive of a locally-built image.

For example, compare:

```
podman push my-image:0.1 oci-archive:/tmp/my-image.tar:my-image:0.1
```

with:

```
podman save --format=oci-archive my-image:0.1 > /tmp/my-image.tar
```

If I compare the two TAR files, they're identical with one exception: the `index.json` in the first TAR file contains:

```
"annotations":{"org.opencontainers.image.ref.name":"my-image:0.1"}
```

but in the second it's:

```
"annotations":{"org.opencontainers.image.ref.name":"localhost/my-image:0.1"}
```

Does this make any practical difference, e.g., in the way the two resulting files can be used?

I expected the two TAR files to be identical.